# VBA Outlook Global Address Book Returns First Entry

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server, addressbook

I am using VBA to open the Outlook/Exchange global address list Dialog, select one or more people, then do some processing with each person. The following is an example of the code:

```
Dim objApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim objDialog As SelectNamesDialog
Dim objGAL As AddressList
Dim objAddrEntry As AddressEntry
Dim objExchUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
Dim strAliasName As String

Set objDialog = objApp.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog
Set objGAL = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List")
With objDialog
    .AllowMultipleSelection = True
    .InitialAddressList = objGAL
    .ShowOnlyInitialAddressList = True
    If .Display Then
        Dim objSelection As Outlook.Recipient
        For Each objSelection In .Recipients
            strAliasName = objSelection.AddressEntry
            Set objAddrEntry = objGAL.AddressEntries(strAliasName)
            Set objExchUser = objAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser
            If Not objExchUser Is Nothing Then
                'Do some processing with exchange user information
                Debug.Print objExchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
            End If
        Next
    End If
End With
```

The problem:  If there is more than one person with the same Exchange alias (this is for a large company where duplicate aliases are common) - e.g. 3 people with the alias of "Doe, John" - the GetSelectNamesDialog returns Exchange information for the FIRST person in the group and not necessarily the person who was selected.

I have tried looking at the different properties available for .Recipients, .AddressEntry, etc. and cannot find any others that return something besides .AddressEntry and .Name. And therein lies the problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to implement? Get all selected users' information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to retrieve address entry by its name if you already have a perfectly good `AddressEntry` object.

The lines

```
strAliasName = objSelection.AddressEntry
set objAddrEntry = objGAL.AddressEntries(strAliasName)
```

need to be replaced with

```
Set objAddrEntry = objSelection.AddressEntry
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all selected recipients in the dialog and check their aliases as well as other information:

```
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Recipient
For Each objSelection In .Recipients
  objAddrEntry = objSelection.AddressEntry
  Set objExchUser = objAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser
  If Not objExchUser Is Nothing Then
     'Do some processing with exchange user information
      Debug.Print objExchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
      Debug.Print objExchUser.Alias
  End If
Next
```

The [Recipient.AddressEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.addressentry) property returns the `AddressEntry` object corresponding to the resolved recipient, not a string.